# How to write multiple lines and read these lines from file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I have written a C++ program which can write single line into the file and can read that line but I want to write multiple lines in the file and want to read that. Anyone can tell me how I can do this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char data[100];
    //Open a file in write mode
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("bfile.dat");
    
    cout<<"Writing to the file..."<<endl;
    cin.getline(data, 100);
    
    //Write inputted data into the file
    outfile<<data<<endl;
    
    //Close the opened file
    outfile.close();
    
    //Open a file in read mode
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("bfile.dat");
    string tp;
    cout<<"Reading from the file..."<<endl;
    while(getline(infile, tp))
    {
        cout<<tp;
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the shown code already does that, it writes and reads lines from a file. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Well, you write data in a loop and read the data back in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is maybe the following code. If this is not the correct answer please be more specific.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("bfile.txt");
    string str;
    cout<<"Writing to the file..."<<endl;
    string isTrue;
    do {
        cout << "Give me a line:  ";
        cin >> str;
        outfile << str << endl;
        cout << "one more line, yes or no? " << endl;
        cin >> isTrue;
    } while (isTrue == "yes");
    cout << "............................." << endl;
    cout << "............................." << endl;
    outfile.close();
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("bfile.txt");
    while(getline(infile, str)) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ShrutikaSubhashDorugade if this is correct answer then accept it as a solution and click to the check mark